# How to change a not required magento custom attribute to a required one?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have a magento customer address attribute and it is not a required one. I want to change it to a required one.

This is the  mysql4-install file i used to add the attribute.

```
$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id', array(
'type' => 'varchar',
'input' => 'text',
'label' => 'Govt ID NO#',
'global' => 1,
'visible' => 1,
'required' => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,
'visible_on_front' => 1
```

));

How can i do this without removing the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* @var $this Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup */
$this->updateAttribute('customer_address','govt_id','is_required','false');
```

Note the difference from `addAttribute()`: `required` vs `is_required`. See [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::_prepareValues()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php#L592).

Comment: If i change the eav attribute table's is required field of the attribute, will there be a problem? also thanks for your answeer benmarks.

Comment: "...will there be a problem?" From an app standpoint, no, because `govt_id` is not a core attribute.